# How to get all of the properties of window in NeoVim?

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to take a look at all of the options which have been set to some window

```
current_window = vim.api.nvim_get_current_win()
vim.wo[current_window].wrap = true
```

Trying just to call `print(vim.inspect(current_window))` gives me this:

```
{
  <metatable> = {
    __index = <function 1>,
    __newindex = <function 2>
  }
}
```

Trying to get size of the table gives me zero:

```
local v = vim.wo[current_window]
print(#v) -- result is 0
```

But at the same time this property exists. The next snippet gives me `true`

```
print(vim.inspect(vim.wo[current_window].wrap)) -- result is true
```

How can I extract all of the window options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came to the next snippet, which will print out options for the current window in neovim

```lua
local all_options = api.nvim_get_all_options_info()
local win_number = api.nvim_get_current_win()
local v = vim.wo[win_number]
local all_options = api.nvim_get_all_options_info()
local result = ""
for key, val in pairs(all_options) do
    if val.global_local == false and val.scope == "win" then
        result = result .. "|" .. key .. "=" .. tostring(v[key] or "<not set>")
    end
end
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Type `:h options.txt`
2. Type `/local to window` and press enter
3. Press `n` or `N` to go forward and backward

Make sure you've read `:h help-summary` and `:h user-manual`

Comment: I want to extract all the properties with their values for the window. Are you suggesting to check them one-by-one manually?

Comment: @AndreiKoch 1. This is "an option", not "a property"; 2. There's `:h option-list` with a short list of all options; 3. There's `set all` command to display current settings; 4. There's `:h :mksession` command that can save local options if `:h 'sessionoptions'` contains `localoptions`; 5. There's `:h nvim_get_all_options_info()` function which output can be filtered by `scope` field; 6. However, the main point is that _every window always has all options set_, though many of them have default values.